# Why is patch rejecting my patch-file on a SVN working copy?

Tags: svn, patch

I have a patchfile like this:

```
Index: dir/file.xml
===================================================================
--- dir/file.xml    (revision 178)
+++ dir/file.xml    (working copy)
@@ -7,7 +7,7 @@
    <markup>
-   <markup />
+   <markup></markup>
    <markup>
    <markup>
@@ -20,6 +20,7 @@
    <markup>
    <markup>
+   <tag>
    <markup>
```

To apply it to the SVN working copy, I branched it using:

```
$ svn copy -r 178 trunk/component/dir branches/mybranch
```

Then I tried

```
$ cd branches/mybranch
$ ls -R
./dir:
file.xml
$ patch -p0 -i ~/patchfile.patch
```

but SVN's output is

```
(Stripping trailing CRs from patch.)
patching file dir/file.xml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 7.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 20.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file dir/file.xml.rej
```

for every file?

What could cause SVN to reject the patch? I am on a UNIX machine but patch and repository have Windows line-endings...

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `dos2unix` tip was not bad but did not solve the problem as suggested.

What I did to actually patch all the files:

```
$ cd branches/mybranch
$ sudo apt-get install tofrodos
$ fromdos ~/patchfile.patch
$ fromdos */*
$ patch -p0 -i ~/patchfile.patch
$ todos */*
```

So basically `patch` seems to have a problem handling `CR/LF` lines under Unix. Converting it to `LF`, then patch and convert it back after patching helped.

Credits to Stefan.

Comment: This also solved my problem, thanks. Indeed it seems that patch doesn't handle CRLF well, even when both in patch and to-be-patched files.

Comment: patch worked fine for me with CRLF, if both patch file & to-be-patched files follow the same line endings (i.e CRLF/LF)

Answer (score 1):

you could try the dos2unix tool on the patch file. That will convert the line endings.

Comment: Did so. Now it does not say "(Stripping trailing CRs from patch.)" anymore. The errors are still present.

Comment: @Stefan dos2unix makes the patching OK. But the result has no line break. In my case for ex, the file contains: catdogcow

Comment: Its not the patch file where this is a problem, it's the source files

Answer (score -1):

Edited:
So we established that `patch` is not an SVN tool.  SVN doesn't have any direct influence on this, unless it created the patch file incorrectly.

Are you sure the patchfile was created from the trunk?  If so, your copy should be identical to the one that the patch was based on, so there should be no reason for it to fail.  The only conclusion I can think of is that there is something wrong with the patch file; it does not match your file.

Confirm that dir/file.xml in your working copy really contains

```
  <markup>
  <markup />
  <markup>
  <markup>
```

starting at line 7. (I'm assuming the code in your question is just an edited copy anyway, because there should be 7 lines there, not 4.)  That is, does the content of the file match the content of the patch?  Pay particular attention to spacing and line endings.  If it does, then there should be no reason why patch would fail that hunk.

Comment: Thank you, Zac. But I know that patch isn't part of subversion. After some tries I also came across this folder question. I should have said, that `dir` is actually in my branch. Trying `patch -p[N]` did return an error like `file not found` or similar. Have a look at my edits. Thanks!